# Javascript statement after facebook sdk is never executed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I have this test to load the Facebook JavaScript SDK synchronously:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>alert('1');</script>     
  <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" />
  <script>alert('2');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For me, the second alert is never shown, any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>alert('1');</script>     
  <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>alert('2');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

More information: [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: indeed, thank you very much! (will accept in 9 minutes...)